# Version solving for certain package versions failed in flutter

Tags: flutter, package, pubspec

I have received this kind error a couple of time before with different packages, usually i just try a combination of different versions till i finally get a match that works. Is there a way to know what package versions are compatible instead of using the trial error approach which is outright time consuming and exhausting.

Initially i though it could be that one of the packages depends on the other, like in this case maybe `flutter_svg` depends on a different version of `flutter_luban` so the version in my pubspec clashes with it, but none of these packages depend on one another after viewing the respective package dependencies.

```
pub get failed (1; So, because sakaHapa depends on both
flutter_svg ^0.17.4 and flutter_luban ^0.1.13, version solving
failed.)
```

Comment: Have you checked this? https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b

Comment: when all packages are compatible with each other then remove  caret sign(^)  **flutter_svg ^0.17.4** to  **flutter_svg 0.17.4** so in this case your project work as it is until you manually update packages version. see this [link](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'pub outdated' command like below.

https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-outdated

Here is column what means.

- Current
  The version used in your package, as recorded in pubspec.lock. If the package isn’t in pubspec.lock, the value is -.
- Upgradable
  The latest version allowed by your pubspec.yaml file. This is the version that dart pub upgrade resolves to. The value is - if the value in the Current column is -.
- Resolvable
  The latest version that can be resolved, when combined with all other dependencies. This version corresponds to what dart pub upgrade gives you if all version constraints in pubspec.yaml are unbounded. A value of - means that the package won’t be needed.
- Latest
  The latest version of the package available, excluding prereleases unless you use the option --prereleases.

```
flutter pub outdated
```

[image]